# XSLT nowrap and XHTML 1.0 Strict

Tags: xslt

we have XSLT to transform XML into HTML in XHTML 1.0 Strict

in XSLT

```
<td colspan="3" nowrap="nowrap">
```

HTML output will be

```
<td colspan="3" nowrap="nowrap">
```

however it will failure in XHTML 1.0 Strict check.
how XSLT can I generate into

```
<td colspan="3" nowrap>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td colspan="3" style="white-space:nowrap;">
```

Answer (score 3):

nowrap without ="nowrap" would be even more wrong in XHTML. XHTML 1.0 Strict does not have the nowrap attribute at all. Use CSS for layout instead.